# Create an array based of another arrays values by defining a key?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to create an array based of another arrays values by defining a key?

E.g.

```
$old_array = array('hey', 'you', 'testing', 'this');

function get_new_array($key) {
global $old_array;

//return new array...
}

$new_array = get_new_array(2); //would return array('hey, 'you', 'testing'); as its the values of all the keys before the key 2 and the 2 key itself
```

Appreciate all help! :B

Comment: If you plan to put this in a custom function I find it a bad idea to use `global`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
function get_new_array($key) {
    global $old_array;
    return array_slice($old_array, 0, $key+1);
}
```

Some suggestions:

- You wanted to return the sub-array up to and *including* the key. It's far more common to instead return up to but *excluding* the key. Hence the `+1` was necassary.
- Using `$old_array` as a global is poor style. I recommend rather passing it as an argument to the function.
- Since `array_slice()` already does what you want, except for minor differences, I'd call it directly rather than writing a wrapper function which hides functionality.

Answer (score 1):

```
$new=array_slice($old_array,0,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use array_slice() function:

```
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

$output = array_slice($input, 2);      // returns "c", "d", and "e"
$output = array_slice($input, -2, 1);  // returns "d"
$output = array_slice($input, 0, 3);   // returns "a", "b", and "c"
```

Link to [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

Comment: It would be nice if you could actually show how to use it to answer this specific question instead of just lifting examples from the manual.